# jquery confirm with modal in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, confirm

Hi I have an linkbutton to delete comment

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CssClass="CommentDeleteBtn"  href="#myModal3" role="button" data-toggle="modal" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Yorum_ID") %>'  Visible='<%# Eval("Yorum_Sahibimi") %>' ToolTip="Sil">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

As you see I added "href="#myModal3" role="button" data-toggle="modal" " to modal confirm.

And my modal box

```
<div id="myModal3" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel3" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                                    <h3 id="myModalLabel3">blabla Header</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Are You Sure</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn blue" onclick="return true;" >Confirm</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

On linkbutton click modal box is displaying.But on confirm button click isn't delete command.About return value ?
(Not about asp.net side delete command)

Answer (score 0):

try adding UseSubmitBehavior="false" to the button code where onclick return true is.

```
<button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn blue" onclick="return true;" UseSubmitBehavior="false">Confirm</button>
```